# Android big image downloading prob : Out of memory

Tags: android, image, download, out-of-memory

I am trying to download a image file. For some cases the image is so big it is giving OutOfMemoryError in the mid-way. How to deal with this situation?

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Download Image");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

                String imageURL = URL[0];

                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    // Download Image from URL
                    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                    // Decode Bitmap
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                // Set the bitmap into ImageView
                image.setImageBitmap(result);
                // Close progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add what you tried , and logcat please.

Comment: i've edited my answer maybe you take a look at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to determine, in what screen or screen part you need to display it. You need to define result sizes (width and height) of container, that will show your image in application. Then, when you receive your image, you need to scale it down to target size and only then show it.

Here is full stack of tutorials how to do it [!link!](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

But I would recomend you use one of 'load images' libraries. **Picasso** is a good example. Please check it out [here](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: Upvoted, but I wanna add that if the OP does not want to use Picasso for whatever reason, he/she should stream the URL to a file via `BufferedInputStreamReader` and then decode that file using the preferred height and width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use libraries like `Picasso` you can use `Volley`.

Go search for `NetworkImageView` , maybe it will hep you.There is one tutorial : [using-volley-to-download-cache-and-display-bitmaps.](http://101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-volley-to-download-cache-and-display-bitmaps.html)

You can take a look at this question too : [how-do-i-properly-set-up-volley-to-download-images-from-a-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988157/how-do-i-properly-set-up-volley-to-download-images-from-a-url)

And here too : [Volley Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Answer (score 0):

> add "android:largeHeap=true" in application tag of manifest file